# how to connect powerbi to bigquery or bigquery to powerbi

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi

I'm having datasets in bigquery google cloud project,
I want to load this data from powerbi,So that I can create visualizations using this bigquery data sets.
Currently I'm able to see the google bigquery in getdata option in powerbi desktop,I tried to connect to bigquery but I'm not abe to see my bigquery dataset in the list,I'm using the same credentials for powerbi and google bigquery.
is there any thig that I need to enable in google cloud side so that it will be visible in the list when I connect from powerbi?

Comment: There are cloud specific sites in stack exchange network. You should check them because they will give you a better help. Stackoverflow is more oriented to coding questions

Answer (score 0):

These are the following steps you can follow to connect GBQ to Power BI.

1. You can write a query and save the table in Google big Query.
2. Go in Power BI, get data and click on more and scroll down there you will find "Google Big Query" click on that.
3. Search your saved table and click on "Direct Query"

I think you will be good to go!!

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using Power BI for Big Query analysis. As of Q1 2019 Power BI still do not support project billing unless manually editing the connexion script, it does not support Sheets federated tables, do not support nested and repeated fields and Power BI DML is nearly unusable with BQ. Microsoft do not seems to be willing to develop the compatibility between Power BI and Big Query further.

Learn more in this article (i am the author): https://medium.com/@remy_david/which-bi-tool-for-big-query-d9eb838ff7ad

Comment: Is this still the case? since this user is facing as it seems to me a compatibility issue https://serverfault.com/q/1022434/581513

Comment: I confirm that I still encounter several compatibility issues with PBI and BQ at the moment and I would not recommend it for production

Comment: Merci bp Rémy :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a client who widely uses Power BI with BigQuery and they have no issues, performance is good, reliable and works very well

To connect to BigQuery go to get data, Database and select Google Bigquery from the scrolling list, then click connect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).